# Getting error while calling service

Tags: php, android

I am developing an app in which i am using php for backend. When i am trying to call the service in my app it is giving me "network error" and value as "null". But when i am putting that same url in google it is giving me the value.

Here is my code for  android:

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity {
public Button scanBtn;
EditText mEdit;
TextView mText;
public TextView t;


@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.first);

    t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t);

    String url = "url?username=test";
    AQuery mAQuery = new AQuery(FirstActivity.this);
    mAQuery.ajax(url, String.class, new AjaxCallback<String>() {

        @Override

        public void callback(String url, String data, AjaxStatus status) {

            super.callback(url, data, status);
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                Log.d("###$Request URL", url + "");
                Log.d("###$Response ", data + "");
                Log.d("###$Status Message : ", status.getMessage() + "");
                Log.d("###$Status Code : ", status.getCode() + "");


                String StringData = "" + data;
                t.setText(StringData);


            }

        }
    });
}
```

From serivice i am getting value like this if it is correct:
        200

And if the username is wrong it is giving:
         no user exist

Where i am wrong i am not able to understand.

Comment: What service? What is the error message? URL in Google? What?

Comment: see my edited question

Comment: you are calling localhost?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `String url = "http://localhost/myfiles/new.php?username=test";`

The fact is probably that your PHP service isn't in your cell phone, so you need to fix it by giving the IP of your server.